# DNN 8.0.3.5 jQuery 1.9.1 Security Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

We are currently failing a security audit due to the following:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2432

Looking at the following folder structure of our install, it seems that jQuery v1.9.1 is installed out of the box:
\Resources\Libraries\jQuery\01_09_01

It would also seem that there is no set way to upgrade the version of jQuery. We must upgrade to v3.0.0 or better. I used [this guide](http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/PostId/308/Upgrading-DotNetNuke-to-Use-the-Latest-jQuery-Ver) to get around the upgrade problem. Unfortunately this breaks the admin with jQuery versions v3.3.1 and v3.0.0 - browser scrolling stopped working as well as pop-ups. For example, cannot uninstall/install an extension.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: The last 1x version of jQuery that was published, or at least that I see in google cdn, is `1.12.4`.  Have you tried upgrading your 1x version past 1.9.1 to see if the issue persists?

Comment: Taplar, no but my understanding is that the security flaw is only fixed in versions 3x up? https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2432

Comment: Aaah, yes, I see that near the end.  You appear to be correct.

Comment: Fix the admin issues and submit a patch? DDN is open source, right?

Comment: Dana, the fact that it is open source is half the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to send an email to security@dnnsoftware.com and see what they suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Joe. Just sent it.